# How to get nested asynchronous calls resolved before completion block

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

Here's the setup. I have a method that has a completion block in which I want to return a list of `Item`s. These `Item`s are fetched from an API. I'd like to have each of the fetches happen asynchronously but ultimately return the `Item`s all together.

Here's what I have:

```
public static func fetchItems(numberOfItems: Int, completion: ([Item]?, NSError?) -> ()) -> Void {
    var items: [Item] = []

    let group = dispatch_group_create()

    for (var itemId = 0; itemId < numberOfItems; itemId++) {

        dispatch_group_async(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {

            APIManager.fetchItemWithId(itemId) {
                (item, error) in

                guard let item = item else {
                    // handle error
                }

                print("Item \(itemId) downloaded")

                items.append(item)
            }

        }
    }

    dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {
        completion(items, nil)
    }

}
```

My output ends up:

```
nil
Item 0 downloaded
Item 1 downloaded
Item 2 downloaded
etc
```

While I am dispatching the the calls for the `Item`s asynchronously, the calls themselves have another asynchronous action inside - illustrated by `APIManager.fetchItemWithId` in the example. So, ultimately, my `completion` is hit before the API requests resolve.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies in this async call to `APIManager`. Your block, dispatched to group finishes before block in that call. Actually, **all** blocks in group finishes before it. If you have option to call sync version of `fetchItemWithId` - use it here. If not - use `dispatch_semaphore_t`.

```
dispatch_group_async(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {

    dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);     

    APIManager.fetchItemWithId(itemId) {
        (item, error) in
            guard let item = item else {
                // handle error
                dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
            }

            print("Item \(itemId) downloaded")

            items.append(item)

            dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
        }

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
}
```

Feel free to ask, if something left unclear. Or, if I misunderstood your intensions

**Update**

I decided to add some comments to make execution flow clear why everything happens the way it does

```
 for (var itemId = 0; itemId < numberOfItems; itemId++) {

 dispatch_group_async(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {
  //1 reach this point for "numberOfItems" times
        APIManager.fetchItemWithId(itemId) {
            (item, error) in

            guard let item = item else {
                // handle error
            }
             //4 we have no guarantee, when this point will be reached relatively to execution flow of "fetchItems" method. 
             //Actually, looks like it is dispatched to some low priority background queue. 
             //When it is first reached, "group" blocks have already been dispatched and successfully executed
            print("Item \(itemId) downloaded")

            items.append(item)
        }
    //2 previous block has been added to some queue. Reach this point for "numberOfItems" times
    }
  }
  //3 reach this point. Most likely all group blocks have already been executed, so completion block is dispatched almost immediately
  dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {
    completion(items, nil)
}
```

Comment: in my example i am using `dispatch_semaphore_t` - so i'm unsure exactly what you mean by saying to use it

Comment: Couldn't find no semaphores in your example. Can you please tell me - where do you use it?

Comment: Glad I could help. Take a look at updated answer - maybe it will make things a little bit  more clear

Comment: @HarlanKellaway I would be much grateful, if you'd mark my answer and, if you think it's worth it, upvote it. After all, I did my best and it helped you =)